# CLP(FD), Map Coloring

Tags: prolog, clpfd, graph-coloring

i am trying to write a map coloring program in prolog CLP. here is the code so far. please anyone help me out here. what is the problem here. and i want to replace maplist function here . any help is appreciated.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
regions(Rs):-
        Rs = [R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6],

        % neighbouring regions have different 
        dif(R1, R2),
        dif(R1, R3),
        dif(R1, R4),
        dif(R1,R6),
        dif(R2, R3),
        dif(R2, R5),
        dif(R3, R4),
        dif(R3,R5),
        dif(R3, R6),
        dif(R4, R5),
        dif(R4, R6),
        maplist(color, Rs).

color(red).
color(green).
color(blue).
color(yellow).
```

Comment: You need to map the colors to integers, like 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed true: The posted code **already works** in any Prolog system that provides `dif/2`.

However, there is a distinct advantage when using **CLP(FD) constraints** for such combinatorial tasks.

Let me show you what I mean. First, here is a straight-forward CLP(FD) formulation of the task:

```
regions(Rs):-
        Rs = [A,B,C,D,E,F],
        Rs ins 0..3,
        A #\= B, A #\= C, A #\= D,
        A #\= F, B #\= C, B #\= E,
        C #\= D, C #\= E, C #\= F,
        D #\= E, D #\= F.
```

I have only:

- changed the variables for readability (`R1` → `A`, `R2` → `B` etc.)
- replaced `dif/2` by the CLP(FD) constraint `(#\=)/2`
- made it all reason over the **integers** 0..3 instead of over atoms, so that CLP(FD) constraints are applicable at all. Note that any problem over finite domains can be mapped to *integers*, and so CLP(FD) constraints are always a suitable choice for such tasks.

First, let us try the **most general query** to see what answers look like in principle:

```
?- regions(Rs).
Rs = [_640, _646, _652, _658, _664, _670],
_640 in 0..3,
_640#\=_670,
_640#\=_658,
_640#\=_652,
_640#\=_646,
etc.
```

This seems quite OK. The constraint solver responds with *residual goals*. Also, we see that our relation *terminates* and is in fact *deterministic*, which is very nice to know. *Labeling* the variables will *retain* the terminating behaviour, so we are not accidentally caught in a loop in other parts of the program.

We can easily obtain concrete **solutions** by *labeling* the variables:

```
?- regions(Rs), label(Rs).
Rs = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3] .
```

Here, each integer corresponds to a unique color. I leave making such solutions nicer to read as an easy exercise.

## Now the point!

### or rather: the dots!

CLP(FD) constraints provide a feature that `dif/2` *doesn't*, and that is constraint **propagation**.

In this case, we initially have the following situation:

[image: Map colouring initial situation]

Here, each small dot stands for a color which we can still *potentially* use for the area in which it is located. At first, the constraint solver has not ruled out *any* color, so we find each of the options in all regions.

The situations changes *drastically* if we assign just *one* of the areas to a fixed color:

```
?- regions([A,B,C,D,E,F]), F = 0.
F = 0,
A in 1..3,
A#\=D,
A#\=C,
A#\=B,
D in 1..3,
D#\=E,
C#\=D,
E in 0..3,
C#\=E,
B#\=E,
C in 1..3,
B#\=C,
B in 0..3.
```

I have only added a *single* unification (`F = 0`), and this has caused the constraint solver to *prune* this option from all adjacent areas:

[image: Remaining options after a single assignment]

Now, I post only one more *additional* unification:

```
?- regions([A,B,C,D,E,F]), F = 0, C = 1.
C = 1,
F = 0,
A in 2..3,
A#\=D,
A#\=B,
D in 2..3,
D#\=E,
E in 0\/2..3,
B#\=E,
B in 0\/2..3.
```

This again *automatically* (i.e., the constraint solver does it for you) removes many other possible assignments:

[image]

With just one more strategic assignment (I leave it as an exercise to find out which), we obtain the following situation:

[image]

Now, the only remaining choices are how to color the single remaining area that is not yet assigned any fixed color. It is easy to see that now *both* admissible colours solve the whole task.

`dif/2` also prunes the search space. However, CLP(FD) constraints perform this powerful pruning on the actual *domains* of variables. This means that many of the values *need not be tried at all*. In addition, based on this reasoning, the constraint solver can more intelligently pick variables that are labeled *next*, which further improves performance in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your program. It works in any Prolog that implements dif/2:

```
?- regions(Rs).
Rs = [red, green, blue, green, red, yellow] ;
Rs = [red, green, blue, green, yellow, yellow] ;
....
```

You don't need library(clpfd) either.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use [answer set programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming), i.e. some forward chaining and a choice operator. Here is some code:

```
:- use_module(library(basic/lists)).
:- use_module(library(minimal/delta)).

edge(r1, r2).
edge(r1, r3).
edge(r1, r4).
edge(r1, r6).
edge(r2, r3).
edge(r2, r5).
edge(r3, r4).
edge(r3, r5).
edge(r3, r6).
edge(r4, r5).
edge(r4, r6).

:- thread_local color/2, vertex/1.

post(color(X,red)); post(color(X,green));
post(color(X,blue)); post(color(X,yellow)) <= posted(vertex(X)).

fail <= posted(color(X,C)), posted(color(Y,C)), {edge(X,Y)}.

regions(Rs) :-
        post(vertex(r1)),
        post(vertex(r2)),
        post(vertex(r3)),
        post(vertex(r4)),
        post(vertex(r5)),
        post(vertex(r6)),
        maplist(color, [r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6], Rs).
```

The above code is a preview of the upcoming release 1.3.1. The aboves gives the following results when run:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 3, Runtime Library 1.3.1
(c) 1985-2018, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- regions(X).
X = [red,green,blue,green,red,yellow] ;
X = [red,green,blue,green,yellow,yellow]
...
```